# Perculiar error when trying to make request to local GQL endpoint

Tags: android-emulator, graphql, react-native

I'm attempting to set up a android application in react-native and it's calling a local API.
Ideally here I'd like the see the API request actually succeed or at least return me a formatted GraphQL exception that should be produced in my back-end.

My GraphQL api is running on localhost:3000

I've already tried the generic solutions for my any question that I've stumbled across

1. Set up an android emulator HTTP proxy to 10.0.2.2:3000

I've set up the ApolloClient like so

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: Platform.select({
            android: 'http://"my machine ip here" / ipv4 /graphql'
        })
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

I've also tried

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: Platform.select({
            android: 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/graphql'
        })
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

The API request is made here:

```
    const [login, {data, loading, error}] = useMutation(LoginUserMutation);

    return <LoginWrapper>
        <Formik
            initialValues={{email: '', password: ''}}
            onSubmit={async ({email, password}) => {
                const user = await login({variables: {email, password}});

            }}
        >
            {({
                  values,
                  handleChange,
                  errors,
                  setFieldTouched,
                  touched,
                  isValid,
                  handleSubmit
              }) => <>
                <Input
                    value={values.email}
                    onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                    onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('email')}
                    placeholder='E-mail'
                />
                <Input
                    value={values.password}
                    onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                    placeholder='Password'
                    onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('password')}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <Button
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                    text='Sign In'
                />
            </>}
        </Formik>
    </LoginWrapper>
};
```

The graphql mutation can be seen here

```
export const LoginUserMutation =
    gql(
        mutation('loginUser',
            params(
                {
                    $args: 'LoginUserInput!'
                },
                {
                    updateUser: params({args: '$args'},
                        {
                            email: types.string,
                        }
                    ),

                })
        )
    );
```

Image of error can be found here - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSv4R.jpg

Partial stack trace here -

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
ApolloError@blob:http://localhost:8081/86efb950-3eff-404f-bc63-41535a310e3a:92518:28
error@blob:http://localhost:8081/86efb950-3eff-404f-bc63-41535a310e3a:93755:30
notifySubscription@blob:http://localhost:8081/86efb950-3eff-404f-bc63-41535a310e3a:141965:20
onNotify@blob:http://localhost:8081/86efb950-3eff-404f-bc63-41535a310e3a:142004:23

Comment: A 400 error means the query you're sending is either malformed or failed validation. Check the actual response received from the server to see what the problem is. You can also update your question on here with the query you're sending if you can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. 

I've got logging enabled on my server and there's no request coming through. & I've just updated it with the GQL mutation

Comment: Depending on where you're logging the request, you won't necessarily log anything if the request is malformed.

Comment: That's true. It's at the resolver level as interceptor so could very well be. But I'm also not seeing it fire off in the network tab either... I'm not entirely sure if you can see that traffic from react native. 

I'll set up a simple fetch request to a controller & see if that returns anything

Comment: Either way, it's not clear what the `mutation` and `params` functions in your snippet do. It'd be more informative to see the actual string that's being passed to `gql`.

Comment: It's ok, I'm pretty sure I've just spotted the issue. 

That mutation is copied from the typed-graphqlify documentation.. it's called updateUser.

That mutation doesn't exist, it should be login..

FEELS BAD MAN

Comment: No worries. You can submit your own answer to this question, or just delete the question if it's not likely to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved the problem.

The mutation should have been

```
export const LoginUserMutation = gql(
    mutation('login',
        params({$args: 'LoginUserInput!'}, {
            login: params({args: '$args'}, {
                token: types.string,
            }),
        })
    )
);
```

The calling of the mutation should have been

```
    const [login, {data, loading, error}] = useMutation(LoginUserMutation);

    await login({variables: {args: {email, password}}})
```